# What does this permission mean, and how do I grant it? accessControlException access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.verbose""read")

Tags: java, javafx-11

If I start my app without invoking the security manager to app runs without error, but when I start app invoking java security manager I receive the following error code.
I'm operating in windows10 environment, eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0), and JavaSE-14, modular programming.
I simply don't understand the permission needed in order to dismiss this error message:
access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.verbose" "read")
If the answer is simply that I need to grant the above permission, then where and who do I grant this permission?
Any nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

The launch code/batch file:

```
@echo off
set JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=
set DIR=%~dp0
"%DIR%\java" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==./jaasPolicy.policy -Djava.security.auth.login.config==./jaasConfig.config %JLINK_VM_OPTIONS% 
-m fm.core/fm.core.main.Driver %*
```

Full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "javafx.verbose" "read")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1152)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:847)
        at java.base/java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.java:266)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$static$0(LauncherImpl.java:122)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.<clinit>(LauncherImpl.java:121)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: I'd say that you have to grant permission in the ./jaasPolicy.policy file : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Comment: I have successfully added the called for permissions to the java.policy file of my runtime image.

Comment: This seems to me to be a problem with running JavaFX with the java.security.manager invoked. When I run the program without the security manager the program fires up with no problems, albeit I'm not instantiating a LoginContext or running my LoginModule. But the Javafx components load correctly with its LoginController class.

Comment: I now receive the following exception: ' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.prism.impl.PrismSettings ' What is com.sun.prism.PrismSettings? Where do I find it? How do I invoke this class? (Note: I have compiled my app with Javafx15, JavaFX14, and JavaFX11. I have settled on JavaFX11. I receive the same error message with all versions.)

Comment: You are misreading the error: "Could not initialize class" means it was found, but failed to initialize. Do note that I commented rather than answered: I know that, with a SecurityManager, you have to grant permissions, but I rarely used that (and I come from using web start ... with the "all permissions" grant, this won't help). You could check $JAVA_HOME\conf\security\java.policy because there is a set of default permissions, which may help Swing/JavaFX working.

Comment: NoDataFound, thanks for taking the time to comment on my content. It is always helpful to here an outsider's take on things. I have partially solved this problem and your intuition was were right in suggesting that the problem is a permission problem. 
I went into the java.policy file and gave the app all permission while running the java security manager. At the very least this showed me that my problem wasn't in my code, but rather my ignorance when it comes to the java.security.manager and java.policy files. Thanks again